# Why do I keep getting " Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types are not supported."?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an entity defined as follows (code generated by the VS2010 POCO generator):

```
public partial class TransactionList
    {
        public int tlRecordId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> tlTracer { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> tlRecordType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> tlPayType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> pdmNumber { get; set; }
        public string pdmName { get; set; }
        public string zoneName { get; set; }
        public string groupName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> serviceCarNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> moneyCarNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> tlPayDateTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> tlExpDateTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> senderPdmNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> tlAmount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> tlTicketNo { get; set; }
    }
```

and there is a second partial class for this class (manually written) which contains the Key attribute.

```
[DataServiceKey("tlRecordId")]
public partial class TransactionList
{ }
```

So there are no complex types/primitives collections defined within this class. If I expose this class using WCF Data Services, I get the following exception:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The property 'TransactionList' on type
>   'DomainObjects.EntityFrameworkModel.Gac' is not a valid property.
>   Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types
>   are not supported.'. See server logs for more details. The exception
>   stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.BuildTypeProperties(ResourceType
>   parentResourceType, IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2
>   childTypes, Queue`1 unvisitedTypes, IEnumerable`1 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadataForTypes(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, Queue`1 unvisitedTypes,
>   IEnumerable`1 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata()
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest()
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The class Gac contains the property TransactionList defined as follows:

```
public IQueryable<TransactionList> TransactionList
{
  get { return _myContext.TransactionList.AsNoTracking(); }
}
```

Why do I get this exception? I do not see any helpful information in the WCF server log. One useful information for you can be that this entity is representing a database view. I already expose a similar entity which contains the same types of properties int, DateTime, string) and it is working.

### ** UPDATE ** Data service definiton added (I left out the IDisposable methods):

```
public class DummyService : DataService<CustomContext>
{
  protected override CustomContext CreateDataSource()
  {
     //I need a single endpoint exposing data from more databases. Here I pass
     //the data needed for the creation of connection strings
     var dataSource = new CustomContext(new int []{1,2,3});
     return dataSource;
   }
}

///This class represents my single endpoint exposing data from various databases.
///Every database has the same DB schema.
public class CustomContext: IDisposable
{
  private static IList<Gac> _gacList;

  //Here I construct the list of accessible data sources - databases. This list
  // can vary
  public CustomContext(IEnumerable<AreaCodes> areaCodes)
  {
    //This is the list of various databases exposed via OData
    _gacList = new List<Gac>();

    foreach (AreaCodes ac in areaCodes)
    {
      //When calling the constructor of Gac, the DbContext gets created.
      _gacList.Add(new Gac(ac.Id));
    }
  }

  //the entity which will be exposed
  public IQueryable<Gac> Gac
  {
      get { return _gacList != null ? _gacList.AsQueryable() : null; }
  }
}

///This class represents a single data source - a database. 
//All databases are exposed over single endpoint
[DataServiceKey("GacId")]
public class Gac: IDisposable
{
    private MyContext _myContext;
    private int _gacId;

  public Gac(int areaCode)
  {
    //Here I finally create my context
    _myContext= new MyContext("...Connection String Generated based on areaCode");
    _myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    _myContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    _gacId = areaCode;
  }  

  //This property uniquely identifies a GAC object. It is an entity key.
  public int GacId
  {
    get { return _gacId; }
  }

  //Expose an entity from the EF layer
  public IQueryable<TransactionList> TransactionList
  {
    get { return _myContext.TransactionList.AsNoTracking(); }
  }

  //...Other about 25 IQueryable properties
}

//generated Entity Framework Conceptual Layer
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{
  //This entity represents my database view which I want to access to
  public DbSet<TransactionList> TransactionList { get; set; }
  //...Other about 25 generic DbSet properties
}
```

Comment: How is your data service defined?

Comment: 'Gac' is a class within my data source. This class contains some properties (one per entity which I want to expose) - the same with TransactionList from above. In the moment I can expose about 30 entities without problems, but if I add this one (TransactionList), the exception will be shown.

Comment: After that, I can access my data service like this: http://localhost:6000/Gac(1)/TransactionList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you expose a property of type IQueryable on your Context class?
If not, then that's the problem. In order for a class to be recognized as an entity it must be exposed in an entity set (have a property on the Context class) and it must have a key (either heuristics or DataServiceKey attribute).

Also note, that it seems you're defining a reflection based service over an EF based data store. This will have problems with more complex queries. WCF DS generates somewhat different expression trees for reflection provider versus EF provider (necessary due to the space of valid expressions supported by these). The trees generated for reflection provider are not always compatible with EF (and the other way round).

If you could share more of your Context class, maybe there's a way to do this without forcing the usage of reflection provider. I understand that you expose several DBs over the service, but how do you run which DB to run the incomming request against? If it can be determined by looking at the request alone, and each request can run only on a single DB, then I think just a bit of logic inside the CreateDataSource should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is one parameter which defines which database should be queried. This parameter must be contained in every request. In the moment, it is a query parameter (?gac=0), but I can set also a header containing this value...I have the control over both the client and the WCF DS. 
I will try to explore the CreateDataSource method-I would like to create a connection to the corresponding EF data store o demand - means to explore the request, pick the corresponding parameter (called 'gac') and create the data source. I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: So I updated the service definition. The property exposed in the context class is of type IQuerable (see "CustomContext.Gac"). The corresponding class "Gac" also has a data service key defined ("GacId").

Comment: But you will need IQueryable<TransactionList> property on the context class. For a type to be correctly recognized as entity type it must have a key property and it must have an IQueryable property on the context.

Comment: This was the missing piece of the puzzle! I somehow misinterpreted your previous answer. So there must be really a IQueryable property for each property which should be recognized as an entity, even though the access to this property does not make any sense and will throw an exception (as in my case).

Comment: If it throws then the protocol will be broken. The property on the context (which defines an entity set) is used to generate unique links for each instance. OData currently doesn't support containment, that is entities which can only exist as children of some parent entity. You can see the "broken" piece by navigating to one of those entities and see its self link. That needs to be always valid URL, but if your top-level property throws, the link will fail. This also means that WCF DS client won't be able to update those entities (since it uses self/edit link to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I think that WCF tries to serialize TransactionList property. You can put attribute which tells WCF to skip property (something like [IgnoreDataMember]) or convert that property to method GetTransationList().

Comment: Actually I need this property, so I cannot skip it so simply. And I want to avoid using service operations here as there are a lot of database views and I would need a service operation for each database view.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can expose generics to web services. As a general rule I wouldn't expose ADO.net data entities to a web service. You should abstract out your data classes from your web service code.

Comment: But this is the purpose of WCF Data Services...I need this functionality of exposing ADO.NET data to a web service.